# Alignment issue of div in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a jquery ui calender that i have placed at left of the page.After calender i have placed second div which is taking full width of the web page.Now i want to add one more div just below the calender but its coming after the second div ..

Here is the link of the image ..

[Please see the web page](http://s28.postimg.org/5468zld0d/pic.png)

Here is my HTML..

```
<div id="datepicker" style="float:left;"></div>

<div id="main" style="float: left; width:83%; margin-left:5px; margin-top:0px;">
<div id="doclist">
    <h2>Documents</h2>
    <ul id="documents">
        <li><a href="#" rel="Document1" title="This is the content of Document1">Document1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="Document2" title="This is the content of Document2">Document2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="Document3" title="This is the content of Document3">Document3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="Document4" title="This is the content of Document4">Document4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="Document5" title="This is the content of Document5">Document5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <!-- Tabs go here -->
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Tab content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="links" style="float:left; margin-left:0px">

<label name="roomOperation" id="roomOperation" style="font-style:normal; font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;"> Room Operation </label>

<br/><br/>

<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football">Check in List</a></li>
<br/>
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis">Check out List</a></li>
<br/>
 </div>
```

Why is this happening..
Please help me  to remove the margin between calender and my hyperlink menu..

Comment: With no code available- it is impossible to help, can you post some CSS, HTML, jsfiddle.net or a live link?

Comment: please post an example of your html and css

Comment: @SW4Please see my HTML..

Comment: @superUntitled I have posted my HTML.Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `position: absolute;` on the `#links` div, and set the CSS `top: ;` value to the same height as your calendar, plus whatever you want as a gap between the two, say 5px, and the `left: 0px;` this should work.

You'll also need to surround all 3 divs with a containing div with CSS `position: relative` to make the `absolute` positioned div keep within the boundaries of the area you want it to be in.

I also believe you could use `float: right;` on the `documents` div and `float: left;` on the other two, but I'm not 100% sure on this, it's worth a try though.